# Canonical way of storing images in android given sqlite progress

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm fully aware that it is generally not recommended to store images as blobs in the database. But I have recently come across [this](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html) website documenting the performance increases of sqlite in reading and writing images (blobs) to the database. Briefly, it is now roughly 35% faster then file storage, for small files. It will take some time until a lot of android devices benefit from this, since old devices use old versions of the db. Nevertheless my future facing question is:

Will this change the preferred way of storing images in android? Would it now be a better idea to store not only uris in the db but also small images, and only where needed load higher resolution images from file storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is now roughly 35% faster then file storage, for small files

If you read the article, it states: "Actual timings vary depending on hardware, operating system, and the details of the experiment, and due to random performance fluctuations on real-world hardware." It is also using the SQLite C API directly, even in the Android tests.

> Will this change the preferred way of storing images in android?

Possibly, but not based solely on that article.

First, the tests would need to be reproduced in the way that Android developers access the database: via Android's Java-based SQLite API (`SQLiteOpenDatabase`, etc.).

Second, speed is only one consideration. Memory is another. Storing an image in the database will consume more heap space than will storing the same image as a file. With a file, `Bitmap` and `BitmapFactory` can work with streams for writing out and reading in the file (PNG, JPEG, etc.). That is not an option in the SQLite case. There, the PNG/JPEG/whatever will be a `byte[]`, taking up heap space and helping to fragment the heap.

Third, other features a team might desire (e.g., FTS indexing, SQLCipher for Android encryption) may impact the performance and would need to be tested.

There are other benefits to storing images in the database directly, such as having an easier time deleting the data (vs. having to delete rows and delete corresponding image files). Teams dealing with small images should run thorough performance tests, on a variety of hardware, before assuming that BLOB-based image storage is a net gain for them.