# how store image in sqlite-database (statically) during installation or runing time?

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite

**Description:**

I'm developing a tailor management app. I store some designs (clothing) images for the app. Some images are statically stored and some images are dynamically stored. Dynamically means that the user is also able to store the images through camera and gallery. I've done this task but I confuse the other task.

**The question:**

I want to store images in sqlite-databse during installation time. I'd like the app to only perform this task once, and not every time that the user starts the app.

**This is my code:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update_design_activity);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kamee_elbow_imagey);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0, stream);
        byte[] bytearry=stream.toByteArray();
        db.insertIntoImageTable("elbow",bytearry);
}
```

This code stores the images repeatedly. I want to store the data and images only once.

[I retrieve all the data in Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI9Kj.png)

How do I go about making the app only store the images once, rather than repeatedly every time the app launches?

Comment: You still shouldn't store images in sql directly.
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816028/canonical-way-of-storing-images-in-android-given-sqlite-progress)

Comment: the question is slightly confusing. IF you want to have some images already stored in the sqlite, you should just include the sqlite db with your app with the images already in it.

there is nothing inherent why you shouldn't store them in sqlite either - it's just that it provides you with little to none practical benefit.

Comment: why? i inserted data directly but the database code i not show in the above code. the images is added but every time add this is one image.

Answer (score 0):

store images to hidden folder. and insert image's path to db.

```
private void storeImage() {
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.imgdir/filename.jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kamee_elbow_imagey);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        db.insertImagePathToDB(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getBitmapFromDisk(){
    String path = db.queryImagePath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that the image name is unique** then a simple query that checks if the image name exists along the lines of:-

```
    public boolean checkImageExists(String imagename) {

        Cursor csr = db.Cursor("yourimagestablename",null,"nameoftheimagenamecolumn=?",new String[]{imagename},null,null,null);
        int rowcount = csr.getCount();
        csr.close();
        return rowcount > 0;
    }
```

You could then do

```
    if(!checkImageExists("elbow")) {
        db.insertIntoImageTable("elbow",bytearry);
    }
```